# Wrong naming "Where in the world" hat

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

See below: The sun is called moon and the moon is called sun.

[image]

Comment: so many funny mistakes this year...

Comment: Yep, it's still there...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct label is now with each version of the `Where in the World` hat

> the sun and the moon
> got confused, asked: who am I?
> "you are me", each said

Comment: With the side affect that if I take off my Sun hat I won't be able to wear it again :/ This is **not** fine :)

Comment: Like @DavidPostill said, why was the *artwork* swapped around, and not the *names*?

Comment: I think that there is some caching involved, investigating...

Comment: Name and artwork are both in sync for me.

Comment: Ok, all should be set now. @DavidPostill as long as you keep wearing the sun, no one can take it from you. Really, you got Moon in the first place, and the wrong image was shown (sorry, I know that that is not the best constellation — I mean consolation — but no easy way to switch them up once they are assigned).

Answer (score 6):

I just earned the sun hat.  I assume it's eclipsed?

[image: Screenshot]