# How did I earn both the Sun and the Moon version of Where in the World?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

It appears that I have earned both versions of Where in the World?

[image]

The description states:

> Ask, answer, or vote ±12h from Dec 21, 0:00 UTC. This hat comes in two versions, **but you can only get one**.
> *(emphasis mine)*

[image]

Comment: I have as well, on different sites. Hey, at least the names have been corrected!

Comment: You beat me to it. I was just going to post the same question :)

Comment: Same, seems there is an issue in the attribution of those hats

Comment: Aww, they were just revoked!

Comment: @CodyGray They may have revoked the hat, but they cannot revoke the memories :'(

Comment: Where can I trade in my newly assigned Sun for the Moon I lost? Black markets welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong naming "Where in the world" hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358052/wrong-naming-where-in-the-world-hat)

Comment: @DavidPostill That's not a dupe: they gave out both versions of the hat just now. (not related to the naming bug) ;)

Comment: Caching. You will lose one of them :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I accidentally assigned the images to the wrong hats, and three of us missed it in testing. I was not able to get to fix this until today, which happened to be a few hours after the hat became activated. So it ended up that some folks got hat with Id 21, which used to have the Moon image, and now has the sun image (and vice versa). Hat labels got corrected, but still had some caching places to clear out. Etc etc, this is the result.

> my apologies
> sun and moon got kerfuffled
> should be all good now