# A question about "Where in the world" hat

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

This is a follow-up question for [How did I earn both the Sun and the Moon version of Where in the World?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358401/259305), in which the description for these hats are included.

> Ask, answer, or vote ±12h from Dec 21, 0:00 UTC.  This hat comes in two versions, **but you can only get one**.

[image]

A user can only get only one hat per site or networkwise?

I got this question because of the first screen capture in the linked question

[image]

which showed the name of the hat received with the name of the associated site.

Comment: It's the same hat as in previous years, and you can get only one of them networkwide.